# Prior YTD Sales Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to pull prior year to date sales data and having a real time of it. 
Tried including a where statement: `WHERE DATABASE1.INVDATE <= GETDATE()` 
but received error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Current (summarized) query:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CAST(DATABASE1.INVDATE AS VARCHAR(8)), 1) AS 'INVDATE',
    CONVERT (DOUBLE PRECISION,DATABASE2.EXTCOSTS) AS 'EXTENDED COST',
    DATABASE1.FISCYR,
    DATABASE1.FISCPER,
    CALENDAR.CalendarYear AS 'CAL YEAR',
    CALENDAR.CalendarPeriod AS 'CAL PERIOD', 

    FROM DATABASE1
    INNER JOIN DATABASE2 ON DATABASE1.TRANSTYPE = DATABASE2.TRANSTYPE
    LEFT JOIN CALENDAR ON (DATABASE1.FISCYR = CALENDAR.FISCALYEAR) AND (DATABASE1.FISCPER = CALENDAR.FISCALPERIOD)
```

What I'm trying to do is pull all the sales data from last year up to today's date.

Comment: Table structure would help out here..

Comment: What is the data type of `DATABASE1.INVDATE` ?

Comment: Does your summarized query above work?  It doesn't have any `where` criteria.  If it does work, notice you are using `cast` to convert it to a `date`.  You'd need to do the same in your `where` criteria most likely.

Comment: if `invdate` is an int, then you'll probably need to do the following `where database1.invdate <= convert(int,convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112))`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare a varchar to a date which is giving  you error.  Why not leave InvDate as a date type?

Comment: InvDate is actually Decimal type, which I have (unfortunately) no control over.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the query form, `invdate` is likely an int. Probably like `20190523`.
You'll have to convert the result of `getdate()` into an int as well.

```sql
...
where datebase1.invdate <= convert(int,convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112))
```

Sql server's precedence rules wants to convert your 8 digit integer into a datetime, which fars exceeds the max value supported for a datetime which is only 2,958,463.

In my opinion, this is a terrible way to store dates. And if you don't care about the time component, you can use the data type of `date`, which only uses 3 bytes per instead of the 4 bytes per `int`

Comment: So this sort of worked.... I'm able to pull the YTD data as long as I also include "AND CALENDAR.CalendarYear = 2019" in the where clause. 

However, I can't seem to figure out how to pull the PYTD info. If I enter: 

AND OEAUDH.INVDATE <= CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112))
AND CALENDAR.CalendarYear = 2018)

 I end up getting ALL of the data from 2018. I only want the data from last year up to today's date so 06/05/2018. How can I accomplish this?